# Can't type in single user mode to change root password

Tags: debian

I'm quite new to linux and I'm trying to boot into single user mode to reset my root password, but whenever I manage to boot up my keyboard doesn't work. I'm using a laptop so there's not much I can do on the hardware side. I've tried plugging in a USB keyboard but that doesn't fix the issue.

Is there any way I can fix this issue, or go about it another way to reset my root password?

Comment: What model of laptop is it? As there might be a bios setting that would allow a usb keyboard to work.

Comment: What is the effect of the non-working keyboard? What are the last lines during boot?

Comment: @fcbsd I'm using a Razer Blade. I can poke around in the BIOS in the meantime and look for an option to enable a keyboard

Comment: @IporSircer how would I be able to freeze/pause the boot log so that I have time to read it? It disappears too quickly for me to see

Comment: @IporSircer The non-working keyboard has no effect. The laptop doesn't recognize it at all

Comment: Any chance you can get a USB keyboard to try?

Comment: @McFizz you might need a legacy usb mode to get the external usb keyboard to work.

Comment: I got this problem on a SuperMicro server with debian 9.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments and your answers to them, your best bet is to boot from an external USB drive and then run '**chroot**' to get yourself into your laptop's environment and then change your laptop's root password there.

If you cannot get your BIOS to recognize USB drives, then you will have to remove the hard drive, connect or install it to another system, and run the '**chroot**' (or even a single user mode if you can boot from your laptop's drive from there.